# Combining one-hot encoded dataframe rows

Tags: r

I "one-hot encoded" a df like this:

df before:

```
C1    C2   C3
a     x     5
b     x     5
c     z     5
```

df after one hot-encoding:

```
Ca   Cb  Cc   C2   C3
1    0   0    x     5
0    1   0    x     5
0    0   0    z     5
```

how can I combine the rows based on identical rows in column C2&C3 (and some more columns with also identical rows) to look like this:

```
Ca   Cb   Cc   C2    C3
1    1    0     x    5
0    0    1     z    5
```

I tried to find a function for this but couldn't find it. Is there any "standardized" functionality in R for this?

If 2 rows have similar C2 values, but different C3 values I don't want to combine them. Basically combine only those rows which have the exact same information besides the values in the on-hot encoded Rows (Ca, Cb, Cc in my example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
aggregate(.~C2:C3,df,function(x) sum(x))
```

Comment: thanks! I didn't think of that. Is there any way to name the columns rather than using " : " ? so instead of C2:C3 something like .~C2, C3, C4, C9, C113 ? [im relatively new to R, so I don't yet understand all symbols; e.g. ".~"]

Comment: what I mean is that the rows which should not be aggregated are C2, C3, C4, C9, C113 (as examples)

Comment: Sure thing, you can use the `+` operator, e.g.: `aggregate(.~C2+C3,df,function(x) sum(x))`, the ~ symbol means: perform the operation per level of the selected columns/variable